# Magento 2: How can I add products in recently viewed via API

Tags: magento2

I am building a mobile app using magento2 rest API, I want to add product in recently viewed when any customer views the product on the mobile app. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below Free Extension which provides REST API for recently viewed products.

It Also provides several Other API's which are missing in Magento Core.

[AddOn Products REST APIs](https://marketplace.magento.com/webbytroops-add-on-product-apis.html)